# Often Misused: File Upload in Java and JSP file

Tags: java, jsp, file-upload, fortify

I am getting the "Often Misused: File Upload" on the below lines.
Can anyone suggest the fix.

1. JAVA file:

   ```
   **public void setAttachedFile(FormFile formFile) { // File upload error at this line**
          attachedFile = formFile;

          if (attachedFile != null) {
               formData.put("attachedFile", attachedFile);
          } else {
                 formData.remove("attachedFile");
           }

         }
   ```
2. JSP file:

   ```
   <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
               <tr>
                 <td class="label" width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
                 <td class="label" width="22%">Select File Name</td>
                    <td class="field" width="26%">
                **<input class="textfield width450" type="file" name="File_Name" maxlength="255" value=""> // Getting                  the fortify here**
                    </td>               
                  </tr>  
              </table>
   ```

Can anyone please suggest the fix/solution

Comment: There's no fix/solution. It's a warning that you might be creating a security flaw if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: Maybe this gives some more information: https://vulncat.fortify.com/en/detail?id=desc.content.html.often_misused_file_upload

Answer (score 0):

Does your backend code verify the file's extension?

If your backend code has to check and verify the file's extension, then you can scan without any issues.

Example in C# like the following:

```
string extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            
if (extension.ToLower().Trim() != ".xlsx" && extension.ToLower().Trim() != ".xls")
{
throw new Exception("Check the extension!");
}
```

and JSP FILE:

```
<input class="textfield width450" 
type="file" name="File_Name" 
maxlength="255" value="" 
accept=".xlsx,.xls">
```

Answer (score 0):

It should not be an error.

It is a warning against malicious hacking; denial of service by high server load and stealing disk resources. Especially hundreds of huge garbage files could be sent by a robot. The form's max-length attribute is not sufficient.

Repeat the browser restrictions in the backend:

```
public void setAttachedFile(FormFile formFile) {
   if (formFile.getFileSize() > 255) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("File too large");
   }
   ...
}
```

(Not sure about which exception is adequate.

But first create your own attack, to test the actual behavior.

To throttle the uploads, have a limited number of uploads and slow down,
is a technical issue out of scope of a simple answer.